# Сеточный окрас трёхмерного графика

Tags: opengl, график

Как в OpenGL нарисовать график (например 1/4 сферы) сеточной окраски?

[image: Пример]

Comment: Проиллюстрируете, что вы имеете ввиду? Также, добавьте в вопрос, должна ли она быть прозрачной? Должны ли линии сетки совпадать с границами полигонов? И определитесь, графика или сферы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос достаточно общий, поэтому даю общий ответ:

1. Рассчитать положения вершин и расположения треугольников/полигонов использующих их.
2. Построить полигональную поверхность
3. Построить сеточный каркас (из линий) по вершинам
4. Орисовать полупрозрачно внутреннюю поверхность
5. Отрисовать каркас из линий
6. Отрисовать полупрозрачно внешнюю поверхность
7. Отрисовать каркас из линий

Шаги 4-7 нужня для корректного наложения прозрачностей. Вы можете их упростить/объединить если подойдет более простой внешний вид.

Comment: Большое спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Для расчёта точек этой поверхности необходимо применить параметрическое уравнение сферы но с другими углами:

судя по вашему рисунку -

зенитный угол меняется в диапазоне

`0 <= theta < PI/2`

а азимутный в диапазоне

`0 <= phi < PI`

тогда для расчёта координат точек сферы, как уже говорилось выше необходимо применить параметрическое уравнение сферы

```
double theta, phi, x, y, z;
for (int i = 0; i <= lats; i++) 
{               
    theta = i * PI * 0.5 / lats;
    for (int j = 0; j <= longs; j++)
    {
        phi = j * PI / longs;                   
        x = sin(theta) * cos(phi);
        y = cos(theta);
        z = sin(theta) * sin(phi);                  
    }               
}
```

где `lats` и `longs` - количество точек + 1 по широте и долготе соответственно

по поводу того, как рисовать:

вам нужно сделать как минимум два `glDraw...` вызова, один для сплошной части другой для сетки только.

Сетку получить можно аналогично как и сферу - указав при этом GL_LINES в качестве примитива отрисовки.